# In GXT when is Change Event fired for Date

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a UI like this

[image]

which uses *com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.DateField*
On "change" event of Date i have a listener. **The Issue here is**

1. The "Change Event" is fired **only** when user changes date **and then click outside** ( somewhere in blank area of form )
2. If user just changes the date **and doesn't** click outside on form , the Change Event is **not** fired.
3. I tried other events like Focus , Blur , Valid the issue with these is that date is coming as null ( and not new changed value ) i want to call my code only when the date value is changed ( without the user need to click outside )

My question is i want to call my code **only when** the date value is changed **without** the user need to click outside... is there a way ??

Answer (score 6):

i think you apply listener on datefield.you have to **apply listener on datepicker** as follow

```
DateField dateField = new DateField();
dateField.getDatePicker().addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<DatePickerEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(DatePickerEvent be) {
            System.out.println("Selected Date : "+be.getDate());
        }
});
```

i hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but this did not work    

**// OLD CODE**
  'date.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener<FieldEvent>() {
            public void handleEvent(FieldEvent be) {
                System.out.println("Selected Date : "+be.getValue());
            }
        });'


  // NEW CODE
    date.getDatePicker().addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<DatePickerEvent>() {
         public void handleEvent(DatePickerEvent be) {
                System.out.println("Selected Date : "+be.getDate());
            }
       });

Comment: @Lav It worked like a charm. Have you tried something like `ValueChangeEvent.fire(dateField, event.getValue());` inside `handleEvent` method?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve the problem is registering ClickEvent for the dateField, dateTextBox in this example:

```
dateTextBox.addClickHandler(this);
```

Then fire the change event

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(datePicker)) {
        dateTextBox.setText(DateTimeFormat.getFormat(getDateFormat()).format(datePicker.getValue()));
        DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createChangeEvent(), dateTextBox);
        datePicker.hide();
      }
    }
```

The only thing with this aproach is that clicking on the year/mouth will hide the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the user does not leave the widget, no blur-, focus, change-event will be fired. If you are interested in value changes, listen to the keyDown (onKeyDown) event and the TriggerEvent (onTriggerEvent).